# Json object selection

Tags: json, select, jq

I have a large JSON object returned from a Google Maps reverse geocode lookup.
in this object there are many possible location details returned.

Using jq how do I select the first returned location with a location_type "ROOFTOP" and get the formatted_address and place_id ?

in the below example the first entry has a location_type of "GEOMETRIC_CENTER"
The second entry has the "ROOFTOP" location_type. I want to ignore the entry with  "GEOMETRIC_CENTER" and only return the fist entry with location_type "ROOFTOP"

Many thanks
Mike

```
  [
   {
     "address_components": [
       {
        "long_name": "30",
        "short_name": "30",
        "types": [
          "street_number"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Allée Jean de Lattre de Tassigny",
        "short_name": "Allée Jean de Lattre de Tassigny",
        "types": [
          "route"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Montpellier",
        "short_name": "Montpellier",
        "types": [
          "locality",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Hérault",
        "short_name": "Hérault",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_2",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Occitanie",
        "short_name": "Occitanie",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "France",
        "short_name": "FR",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "34000",
        "short_name": "34000",
        "types": [
          "postal_code"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "30 Allée Jean de Lattre de Tassigny, 34000 Montpellier, France",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 43.6097932,
          "lng": 3.8817559
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 43.6094097,
          "lng": 3.881321299999999
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 43.6095516,
        "lng": 3.881559199999999
      },
      "location_type": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 43.6109504302915,
          "lng": 3.882887580291503
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 43.6082524697085,
          "lng": 3.880189619708498
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJ13k0paCvthIRcTgwBrisc10",
    "types": [
      "premise"
    ]
   },
   {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "8",
        "short_name": "8",
        "types": [
          "street_number"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Rue Michelet",
        "short_name": "Rue Michelet",
        "types": [
          "route"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Montpellier",
        "short_name": "Montpellier",
        "types": [
          "locality",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Hérault",
        "short_name": "Hérault",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_2",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Occitanie",
        "short_name": "Occitanie",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "France",
        "short_name": "FR",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "34000",
        "short_name": "34000",
        "types": [
          "postal_code"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "8 Rue Michelet, 34000 Montpellier, France",
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 43.60911189999999,
        "lng": 3.8814264
      },
      "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 43.61046088029149,
          "lng": 3.882775380291502
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 43.60776291970849,
          "lng": 3.880077419708498
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJ2UaGt6CvthIRJoNW7vS2Ibs",
    "plus_code": {
      "compound_code": "JV5J+JH Montpellier, France",
      "global_code": "8FM5JV5J+JH"
    },
    "types": [
      "street_address"
    ]
   }
  ]
```

Comment: This serialization has errors, can you correct it? I can't parse.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `.[0]` to obtain the first object satisfying, it would be more efficient to use `first/1`.  Here is a solution using `first/1` and `..`:

```
$ jq 'first(..|objects|select(.geometry.location_type == "ROOFTOP"))
      | {formatted_address, place_id}' input.json
{
  "formatted_address": "8 Rue Michelet, 34000 Montpellier, France",
  "place_id": "ChIJ2UaGt6CvthIRJoNW7vS2Ibs"
}
```

Using `first`in this way avoids having to compute the entire array before taking the first element.

### Alternatively ...

Retrieving the first top-level object, without using `..`:

```
first(.[] | select(.geometry.location_type=="ROOFTOP"))
```

Comment: Thankyou peak but unfortunately this did not work for me as I could not access the place_id and formatted_address

Comment: @peak For my info, why is `first` more efficient than `.[0]`?

Comment: Thankyou again peak, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the entries are enclosed in an array, you can use this `jq` filter that gives all objects having `ROOFTOP` as `location`:

```
jq '.[] | select(.geometry.location_type=="ROOFTOP")' file
```

If you want to select only the first one from all objects, use the following:

```
jq 'map(select(.geometry.location_type=="ROOFTOP"))|.[0]' file
```

And you only need need some of the values, pipe it another filter like this:

```
jq 'map(select(.geometry.location_type=="ROOFTOP"))|.[0]|.place_id, .formatted_address' file
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply oliv, when there are multiple entries with "ROOFTOP" this returns them all. Im looking for only the first entry and return the place_id and Formatted_address of that entry only.

Comment: @MikeC If you mean the array elements, the answer is yes. Just change the `.[0]` by the index of the element you want to access.

Comment: Many thanks this has given me what I required i can access any of the elements using the second of the options here :)